# How to use store subscribe with TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, vuejs2, vuex

I've set up a simple Veux store:

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    searchList: [],
  },
  mutations: {
    createList(state, payload) {
      state.searchList = payload;
    },
  },
  getters: {
    list(state) {
      return state.searchList;
    },
  },
});
```

In a function I get a array of objects and I commit them into the state:

```
.then((data) => MovieSearchResults.commit('createList', data));
```

Then in a different component I want to use the data from the store to populate a list:

```
import MovieSearchResults from '../../../stores/MovieSearchList';

@Component
export default class MovieSearchResultList extends Vue {}
MovieSearchResults.subscribe((mutation) => {
  console.log(mutation.payload.results);
});
</script>
```

When I mutate the state I see the payload in the console log in the `MovieSearchResultList` component, but that subscribe is outside the class so I can't actually use the data.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What's the difference between `MovieSearchResults` vs `MovieSearchResultsList`?

Comment: MovieSearchResults is the name I gave to the store (see edit). MovieSearchResultsList is the name of the class.

Comment: I think that the subscription is simply not needed. `MovieSearchResultList` should have a `computed` with some function `foo` that evaluates `searchList`. This way, whenever the `store.state.searchList` changes, it will cause the computed property to re-evaluate, and trigger associated DOM updates. [see example in the official docs](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html#getting-vuex-state-into-vue-components).

Comment: Was a bit hard to figure out how to implement this in TypeScript but got it working thanks to your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm using TypeScript the answer wasn't very clear since I can't use `compute`. But after some [digging](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-write-a-vue-js-app-completely-in-typescript/) I found that TypeScript uses `getters` for compute.

So what I did was add a `get` method that returns the `searchList` state:

```
type Movie = {
  title: string;
  id: number;
}

@Component
export default class MovieSearchResultList extends Vue {
  get searchList(): Movie[] {
    return MovieSearchResults.state.searchList;
  }
}
```

And for the template I used:

```
<template>
  <ul>
    <li v-for='movie in searchList' :key='movie.id'>
      {{ movie.original_title }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>
```

This list gets updated when the state changes.